# Unable to start vncserver in RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, services, vnc

Following the instructions from `Redhat` documentation ([TigerVNC](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-TigerVNC.html)), I've installed `VNCserver` in `RHEL 7`. When I try to start the vncserver service, it returns an error

```
#systemctl start vncserver@:1.service
Job for vncserver@:1.service failed. See 'systemctl status vncserver@:1.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

I found the status of the vncserver as:

```
vncserver@:1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2015-10-22 14:35:57 EDT; 13s ago
  Process: 6640 ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l MyUser -c /usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1280x1024 (code=exited, status=98)
  Process: 6637 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || : (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service: control process exited, code=exited status=98
systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
systemd[1]: Unit vncserver@:1.service entered failed state.
```

Updated the users in `vncserver@.service` file and have reloaded the daemon. Any ideas on how to resolve this.

Comment: did you run, as user, `vncpasswd` to set up a password?

Comment: @meuh Yes, I run as a user.

Answer (score 3):

Got lucky on this one *([thanks to this](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2014-July/452223.html))*.

Go to the folder "/tmp/.X11-unix/" and list content:

```
$ cd /tmp/.X11-unix/

$ ls
```

I found there several X0, X4, X5... files *(one for each of my blocked user)*.

Each one is associated to a session and should be deleted when the session is closed, BUT it is not always.

DELETE IT:

```
$ sudo rm X4
```

and VNC session should start:

```
$ systemctl restart vncserver@:4.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit file `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:3.service`; Group should be different than User. It failed on me when the user=group.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was incorrect username/group in the settings file. In the `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service` file, I forgot to change the user and group details. Once I changed this to the correct user, it worked.

```
[Service] 
User=jon
Group=jon
```

Comment: Can you relate this to the issue that the user in the question has, and say something about what that means they should do to resolve their problem?

Comment: In the `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service` file, i forgot to change the user and group details. Once i changed this to the correct user, it worked.

`vi /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service`

[Service] 
User=jon
Group=jon

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me on Centos7:

```
$ rm /tmp/.X11-unix/*
```

Comment: This doesn't seem very different from the other answer, except that it isn't as surgical as that one.

Comment: LOL, no. This fixes zilch. In fact, after deleting those files, `vncserver` keeps complaining that those files are there even after I've double-checked they're gone and `rm -f` gives an error when trying to delete them, because they're already gone.